# is defined but never used no-unused-var

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm New to React, and I'm trying to learn about React Component right now. but when I create nameList.js, add data in there, and export to app.js, it does not show anything in the browser. I read some answers in Stackoverflow and tried it. but not show anything.

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import nameList from './Components/nameList';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App" >
            <nameList/>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**nameList.js in Component Folder**

```
import React from 'react';

function nameList() {
    return (
    <div>
       <h1>Name List</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Stu1</li>
            <li>Stu2</li>
            <li>Stu3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default nameList;
```

I need to get data in nameList.js into App.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure that nameList starts with a capital letter so that React knows it's a component and not an HTML element.

```
import React from 'react';

function NameList() {
    return (
    <div>
       <h1>Name List</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Stu1</li>
            <li>Stu2</li>
            <li>Stu3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default NameList;
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import NameList from './Components/nameList';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App" >
            <NameList/>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

https://react.dev/learn/your-first-component#what-the-browser-sees